# How to configure watchdog mode with interrupt in MSP430F5358?

Tags: microcontrollers

I am using the MSP430F5358 controller and want to enable the watchdog timer to reset the controller when some malfunction occurs with the Software. I need to add watchdog Interrupt so that it completes some power down sequence before resetting the controller?
I have checked the resource explorer for it and all 5 examples are not helping for my requirements.

Comment: not an IoT question ... belongs at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I agree that this belongs in the electronics stack exchange. Also if possible, consider moving the power down sequence to a "bring system to known safe state at startup" sequence.